# Should I delete a solution from the question body?

Tags: discussion

If a user solves their own question, and updates their question with working code while not changing the rest of their question, what should I do?

The user in my particular case simply added a paragraph of what the problem was and then new code that worked.

My initial thoughts were:

1. Just edit the question and delete the answer
2. Remove the question from the answer and put it into an answer myself (although this feels like stealing potential Karma)
3. Comment on the question that the Op should **answer** their question rather than just update their question
4. Do nothing and run away to Meta

I actually did step 3, and came here for advice.

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078247/deleting-one-image-channel-using-cuda-and-opencv). However, I am aware that it may at this point just be closed as typographical error/too specific for Stack Overflow.

Comment: TBF In this instance the user was responsive and responded to my comment and created their own answer.

Comment: 3 is a fine solution. Note that if you post an answer and don't feel comfortable taking credit for the work and reputation it earns, you can create a community wiki (little checkbox right lower corner of the answer textbox). That way, you don't earn reputation, and others (mainly the OP) are free to edit the answer).

Comment: He took care of it, your comment was good enough to get him to do it right.  Pretty unusual btw.  Otherwise what I do, salvaging a truly useful answer from such an edit is not very common.